# Solder USB wifi right on to raspberry pi zero

Tags: usb, hardware, pi-zero-w

I am trying to solder a wifi adapter right on to my raspberry pi zero so it takes up less space.

I've followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tK_eVTTs_fQ&t=614s) and some other diagrams on how to wire usb devices right on to the pi zero. Unfortunately, when i solder the adapter on the pi like this:
[image: wifi adapter connected to my pi zero]
then the pi doesn't detect it. It just runs normally like without it.

Some additional information:

1. I know that the wifi adapter works and is compatible with linux (i tried it before attempting this).
2. The adapter works fine when it's connected via a usb header so it isn't broken.
3. The usb plug on my pi works normally.

Comment: Can you verify that the electrical connections are good with a multi-meter? Do any lights turn on on the WiFi adapter when it is connected like this or can you measure any voltage? Can you verify D+/D- aren't short-circuiting? Have you doubled checked that they are soldered on the right way around and haven't been reversed?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Fred , i lost all hope because nobody could help me. The connections are good. The wifi adapter has a LED that blinks when its working, but it isn't when i try to connect it like this. D+/D- aren't short-circuiting and i am sure that they are soldered on the right way around. Maybe it has something to do with the fifth pin on the micro usb? It does work when i connect it with an otg usb a to micro usb adapter though.

Comment: Forgot to say that my multi-meter reads 3V (2,75V?) on D+/D- and normal 5V on the 5V/GND.

Comment: Can you use the OTG adaptor to check continuity through to the ends of the soldered wires? The 5th pin on the Micro USB header isn't used on a regular Type A connector and shouldn't matter. If the wiring is fine, the only other thing I could think of would be a voltage drop on 5V during power on or possibly the wire gauge is too small.